# How could I simulate a lack of file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

I would like to provoke a situation where there is no file descriptor remaining.

I have been thinking about 2 possibilities:

1. Opening thousands of files randomly until the result of open is -1
2. Set a very low number of file descriptor available (let's say stdin, stdout and stderr).

How would you do it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can limit the number of file descriptors a process can open under Linux using ulimit.

Executing `ulimit -n 3` before running your C program should make it an error to open any more files, since stdin, stdout, and stderr take up the first 3 descriptors.

An example:

```
$ ulimit -n 3
$ echo > /dev/null
zsh: too many open files: /dev/null
```

The shell process itself attempts to open /dev/null to redirect stdout before closing it there, therefore it gets an error. Your C program will be fed the exact same error the first time it calls **fopen**, **open**, **socket**, etc (or anything that allocates a new file descriptor).

Comment: Does the shell create file descriptors when spawning an external program?  I think a pipeline would at least need to use `pipe(2)` and various kinds of substitution could also cause issues.  At the very least, you should be aware that this ulimit will greatly handicap your shell.

Comment: @Kevin, redirection can be done through `dup(2)`,`dup2(2)`, or `pipe(2)`, but when the shell simply spawns a program and just forks and uses `execve(2)` which passes over the first 3 descriptors without creating new ones to the subprocess. For actual redirection, regardless what you use, a descriptor is created, since the descriptor is duplicated before it can be reassigned/attached, as stdin is already bound to the shell's stdin descriptor. The limit can just be raised again after your test up to the default upper limit (see the default with `ulimit -n`).